# Descomprimir archivos ZIP

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un método que descomprime ficheros ZIP, pero tengo un problema cuando intento descomprimir un fichero en mi *servidor de datos*.

***Método:***

```vb
Public Function descomprimir(rutaZip As String, Optional carpetaDestino As String = "")

        If carpetaDestino = String.Empty Then
            carpetaDestino = "unzip"
        End If

        Dim shObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"))
        Dim destino As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaZip) & "\" & carpetaDestino

        'Crea el directorio donde se van a extraer los archivos
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destino)
        Dim output As Object = shObj.NameSpace((destino))
        Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((rutaZip))

        'Extrae los elementos del archivo zip
        output.CopyHere((input.Items), 4)

        Return destino
    End Function
```

La siguiente línea me devuelve *`Nothing`* solo si el archivo no existe (en teoría):

```
Dim input As Object = shObj.NameSpace((rutaZip))
```

Pero he intentando a poner la anterior línea en un `If File.Exists(rutaZip) ...` y siempre entra porque detecta que si que existe el fichero. (Ya sea en un `.zip` del servidor de datos, o del ordenador en local)

***Ejemplo*** *de ruta del servidor de datos:*

> ```
> \\ServerData\data\docs\archivo.zip
> ```

***Ejemplo*** *de ruta en local:*

> ```
> C:\Users\so\Desktop\archivo.zip
> ```

*(Acepto sugerencias sobre cómo hacerlo de manera más sencilla)*. Uso NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he hecho con la librería **[DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)** de la siguiente manera:

```vb
Private Sub MyExtract()
   Dim ZipToUnpack As String = "\\ServerData\data\docs\archivo.zip"
   Dim UnpackDirectory As String = "C:\Users\so\Desktop\prueba"
   Using zip1 As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipToUnpack)
        Dim e As ZipEntry

        For Each e In zip1
            e.Extract(UnpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: vi la pregunta hace unas horas, pero como no se nada de vb, no le comente nada aun asi la mire por veia algo, la estaba vigilando para saber el porque nunca esta demas, ver cosillas por si algundia tengo que usar vb, todo este rollo era simplemente para decirle que puede marcar la respuesta como aceptada aun siendo suya, pasado un tiempo. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Tengo que esperar 2 días para marcar mi respuesta como respuesta válida. Un saludo